# How to add collate in laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collate

In my project I am allowing user to search any thing. Recently facing an issue in Like query.

```
Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

I got a solution for this issue but now want to convert in laravel query.

How I can write `user.name LIKE _latin1 '%aaa‬%' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci` this in ->where() of laravel

and my current query code is `$query->where('user.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereRaw` like this

```
$query->whereRaw("user.name LIKE _latin1 '%aaa‬%' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci");
```

Comment: Is there a way to use COLLATE inside where().

Comment: @Rafikmalek you have to use `whereRaw` not just `where`.